# using array in WHERE IN in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, where-in, cakephp-3.2

I'm working on CakePHP 3.2

I want to use an array in the query `WHERE IN ()`

The code is as

```
$filter_p_t = $this->request->query('p_t');

$pros10 = $this->Products->find()
 ->where([
   'SellerProducts.stock >' => 0,
   'SellerProducts.status' => 1,
   'Products.p_status' => 1,
 ])
 ->contain([
   'SellerProducts',
   'ProductTypes.Subcategories.Categories',
 ]);
```

Here `$filter_p_t` is an array from url with parameter

```
/products/display/1?p_t[]=1&p_t[]=86
```

I want to include `$filter_p_t` in to the `where` condition to find all `IN(1,86)`

**How can I use php array to the WHERE IN condition in CakePHP 3?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `IN` keyword directly after the column.  This is assuming that `$filter_p_t` is an array like `array(1, 86)`.

```
->where(['id IN' => $filter_p_t]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses